# ImageButton background not changing

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

on clicking the play button if music is playing the music should pause and image of button should change to pause button and vice versa

I dont know whats wrong with the logic please check.

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.mpPlay: // bPlay
            if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
            }
            if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
            {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
            }               
            break;
          }
```

Comment: try calling `bPlay.invalidate();`

Comment: throw some breakpoints and debug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`setImageResource(id);`

or

`setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, id));`

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your second "if" statement with an "else". When your code is executed, the media player is not playing so your first "if" statement gets executed. This turns on your media playback. However, when your code gets to your second "if" statement, your media will be playing, so it immediately turns back off.  Replacing your second "if" statement with an "else" will ensure that only one of the options (turn media playback on or turn media playback off) will be executed on any given onClick().

```
        if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
        {
            mediaPlayer.start();
            bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
        else
        {
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            bPlay.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pause);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understood

```
ImageButton bPlay = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.mpPlay);
//mpPlay is id of your ImageButton for play button in xml file
```

is Ok.

So, try this:

```
    public void onClick(View v){
        switch (v.getId()){
            case R.id.mpPlay:
                if(!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                    bPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                   //pause icon during player plaing
                } else if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
                    mediaPlayer.pause();
                    bPlay.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                    //play icon during player on pause
                }               
             break;
          }
}
```

In some way, it's logically